# Titanium - Issue in adding numbers

Tags: javascript, geolocation, titanium, appcelerator, addition

I am getting a latitude value using forwardGeocoder and I am adding the obtained latitude value with a decimal number. Have a look at the below code.

```
Ti.Geolocation.forwardGeocoder(textField.value, function(e) {
            var a = e.latitude;
            var b = 0.1;
            var c = a+b;
            Ti.API.info('result c:  '+c);
});
```

The result shows

```
[INFO] result c:  40.7145500.1
```

The problem is, the given value is not added to the latitude value, it is just printed along with the sting.

When I tried subtraction, it worked fine. When I tried using custom values for `a` and `b`, it worked fine.

```
Ti.Geolocation.forwardGeocoder(textField.value, function(e) {
            var a = 0.1;
            var b = 0.1;
            var c = a+b;
            Ti.API.info('result c:  '+c);
});
```

The result shows

```
[INFO] result c:  0.2
```

So, how could I add a number to the obtained latitude? Help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `e.latitude` is a string, and JavaScript is converting the `Number` to a string and concatenating it.

Try this:

```
Ti.Geolocation.forwardGeocoder(textField.value, function(e) {
            var a = parseFloat(e.latitude);
            var b = 0.1;
            var c = a+b;
            Ti.API.info('result c:  '+c);
});
```